# Why does my hostname show as "Unknown-08-00-27-50-25-08" when using a bridged connection?

Tags: linux, networking, oracle-linux, oracle

I am running an Oracle Linux 7 VM. I have booted the VM up separately with different network options, NAT and Bridged connection. I would like to use a bridged connection so I can SSH in easily.

When I boot up the VM using NAT I get the following as my hostname

`root@localhost`

When I boot up using a bridged connection I get the following

`root@Unknown-08-00-27-50-25-08`

Why is this happening and how can I set the machine to a proper name when using a bridged connection?

Comment: Possibly related: [Host name changed remotely by wifi?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/243554)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a MAC Address is part of the new host name after bridging. Could you have booted up with networking in DHCP since the bridge may be connecting to a DHCP server, where NAT did not? Run ifconfig and see if the 08-00-27-50-25-08 appears as the MAC address. Is the VM host connected to another network which could provide DHCP? What is the config for the VM interface, a static address or DHCP. Look in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts for ifcfg files which are for IF configs. Also NM, network manager, could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

It turns out NetworkManager was overriding my transient hostname via DHCP.

I fixed this by adding the following line to my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 file

`DHCP_HOSTNAME=hostname`